# Twig creating a rowspan on loop

Tags: html-table, twig

I have this table data:

```
Name | Score | Remarks
john |  80   |   pass
jane |  85   |   pass
```

How to make it look like this:

```
Name | Score | Remarks
john |  80   |   pass
jane |  85   |
```

Remarks table head should create a rowspan of 2 but I'm having a prob on how to implement using twig template. Below is my code:

```
{% for name in names %}
      <tr>
          <td class="text-center">{{name.name}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{name.score}}</td>
          <td class="text-center" rowspan="2">{{name.remarks}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Name | Score | Remarks |
john |  80   |   pass  |
jane |  85   |         | pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{% if loop.index0 % 2 == 0 %}
    <td class="text-center" rowspan="2">{{name.remarks}}</td>
{% endif %}
```

`% 2` corresponds to `rowspan="2"`

Comment: I posted a solution that will work with any data (more that 2 for example)

Comment: @mykiwi: your solution is better for generic cases but more complicated to set up for a simple case. In any case I like and I +1 for yours:)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
{% for name in names %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{name.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{name.score}}</td>
        {% set rowspan = new_rowspan(names, loop.index0, 'remarks') %}
        {% if rowspan %}
            <td class="text-center" rowspan="{{ rowspan }}">{{name.remarks}}</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And add a Twig extension:

```
class YourTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_Function('new_rowspan', [$this, 'calculateRowspan']),
        );
    }

    public function calculateRowspan($names, $from, $column)
    {
        // check if previous column has the same value
        if ($from > 0 && $names[$from - 1][$column] === $names[$from][$column]) {
            return;
        }

        for ($to = $from + 1; isset($names[$to]) && $names[$to][$column] === $names[$from][$column]; $to++);

        return $to - $from;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this would help me in the future :)